# Can I copy test cases based on results, in MTM/Test Manager?

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

I am having trouble managing test cases in MTM.

My requirement is to identify all test cases within a suite with a particular status, in this case either Active, Blocked or Failed.

I would then copy these to a new suite. Test suites are created for each weekly cycle, so to plan next week's testing I want to start with all tests that have not passed... the actual process seems simple - I can see the results in the Test view, but I cannot copy test cases from here, only from the Plan view. The Plan view does not show results though.

I have resorted to taking a screenshot from Test view and then doing the copying of required test cases as needed within Plan view.
This is a frustrating process as I have to manage a large number of test cases.
I have used the web front-end to view results as well, in the Test view of TFS, but again this only shows me results and I cannot see a way to copy any of the qualifying test cases to another test suite.

Hopefully this makes sense and any suggestions on workarounds or improvements to this workflow would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there isn't any way to do this. The test result outcome status is a part of test result data, which is stored separately from test case. So it is impossible to filter the test case by outcome status and then copy them to another test suite from MTM for now. You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) for this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, fingers crossed for a future feature.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below link and steps:

link:`http://www.tfswhisperer.com/post/2014/08/22/Referencing-and-Copying-Test-Cases-in-MTM-2013-a-Lesson-in-Patience`

1)Add existing test cases
2)Create test suites by referencing existing test cases
3) Create copy and add to suite
4)You might have noticed a Copy (CTRL + C)
5)Create a copy of this work item (including links)